# Is there any way to make constructor understand parameter type automatically?

Tags: c++, oop, c++17

I have a `Feature` class which has a `public vehicle_type` in it and I have 3 candidates for `vehicle_type` variable which are; `Car`,`Truck` and `Motor` classes. When I call constructor for `Feature` class, well I want my program to get which  vehicle type was called with constructor automatically. I actually tried to use `Templates` for the problem but it didn't work. So, can someone tell me how to achieve this with or without using `Templates`.

This is my `Feature.h` file:

```
#ifndef FEATURE_H
#define FEATURE_H

#include <string>
#include "../includes/Car.h"
#include "../includes/Truck.h"
#include "../includes/Motor.h"


template <typename T>
class Feature{
    public:
        Feature();
        Feature(int w, std::string b, std::string clr, double p, T v_t);
        T vehicle_type;
        int wheels;
        std::string brand;
        std::string color;
        double price;

};


#endif
```

This is my `Feature.cpp` file:

```
# include "../includes/Feature.h"

template <typename T> 
Feature::Feature(int w, std::string br, std::string clr, double p, T v_t){wheels = w; brand=br; color = clr; price=p;  vehicle_type = v_t; }
Feature::Feature(){}
```

and lastly, this below is the error occurs when I hover my mouse  on `Feature` constructor in the `Feature.cpp` file.

```
name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name
```

Feel free to ask for more information. Thanks.

Comment: (A) wrong syntax for defining a template class constructor (B) template method definitions must be defined in a header file (C) class template deduction is new as of like C++17 or C++20. What version are you using?

Comment: @MooingDuck I'm using c++17.

Comment: Have you considered using inheritance / polymorphism for this, rather than a template?

Comment: @PaulSanders No I haven't  actually.  I  thought maybe, I could use 3 constructors for each 3 different classes but I think this is not the best idea.

Comment: With inheritance, you can have the constructor of each derived class pass the appropriate vehicle type to the parent constructor (and drop the template completely).  That would be my choice.

Comment: @AliZiyaÇEVİK: You can't put the implementation of templates in a .cpp file in most cases.

Comment: Are `Car`, `Truck`, and `Motor` actual class types that you instantiate and pass to `Feature`?  Or are they values in an `enum` instead?  Your constructor code suggests they are distinct types, but the name `vehicle_type` implies an `enum`.  What is the use-case for `Feature` exactly?

Comment: @RemyLebeau They are all actual classes inherited from a ```Vehicle```class. I still couldn't find a way to achieve this. I tried inheritence  as @Paul Sanders said but couldn't find a way it works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to supply the template declaration and the fix the syntax:

```
template <typename T> 
Feature<T>::Feature(int w, std::string br, std::string clr, double p, T v_t);

template<class T>
Feature<T>::Feature();
```

Comment: Well, I thought ı shouldn't use ```templates``` at ```.cpp``` files.

Comment: @AliZiyaÇEVİK That too, yes

Comment: @MooingDuck is this solution above implemented in a ```.h``` file or ```.cpp```file ?

Comment: @AliZiyaÇEVİK ["Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?
"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)